# menu in my wordpress theme don't show 3 level it's only show 2 level

Tags: php, wordpress

i want show three level in my main menu but it's only show two level this is my function for menu

```
function print_menu($menu_name){
    //  $menu_name = 'main-menu';
    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        $menu_list = '';
        $count = 0;
        $submenu = false;
        $cpi=get_the_id();
        foreach( $menu_items as $current ) {
            if($cpi == $current->object_id ){if ( !$current->menu_item_parent ) {$cpi=$current->ID;}else{$cpi=$current->menu_item_parent;}$cai=$current->ID;break;}
        }
        foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
            $link = $menu_item->url;
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $menu_item->ID==$cai ? $ac2=' current_menu' : $ac2='';
            if ( !$menu_item->menu_item_parent ) {
                $parent_id = $menu_item->ID;$parent_id==$cpi ? $ac=' active' : $ac='';
                if(!empty($menu_items[$count + 1]) && $menu_items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent == $parent_id ){//Checking has child
                    $menu_list .= '<li class="nav-item dropdown'.$ac.'"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="'.$link.'" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span>'.$title.'</span></a>';
                }else{
                    $menu_list .= '<li class="nav-item '.$ac.'">' ."\n";$menu_list .= '<a href="'.$link.'" class="nav-link '.$ac2.'"><span>'.$title.'</span></a>' ."\n";
                }

            }
            if ( $parent_id == $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) {
                if ( !$submenu ) {
                    $submenu = true;
                    $menu_list .= '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">';
                }
                $menu_list .= '<a href="'.$link.'" class="'.$ac2.' dropdown-item">'.$title.'</a>' ."\n";
                if(empty($menu_items[$count + 1]) || $menu_items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu){
                    $menu_list .= '</div>' ."\n";
                    $submenu = false;
                }
            }
            if (empty($menu_items[$count + 1]) || $menu_items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ) { 
                $menu_list .= '</li>' ."\n";      
                $submenu = false;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    } else {
        $menu_list = '<li>Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not defined.</li>';
    }
    echo $menu_list;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, we know what you want. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i can show my submenu in 3rd level how can i edit my code

Comment: @pavel how can I change my menu for shoe 3 levels of submenu?